# Creating a cookie with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set/unset cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)

How would I go about creating a cookie using jquery to save a number of form fields on a website, also is it possible to save a cookie without using a save function, but instead when the each textfield, checkbox etc. is interacted with?

Comment: Many answers here - http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+cookie&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t

Answer (score 2):

jQuery makes cookies very straightforward and easy to use.

If you want to set a cookie, simply add this line of jQuery code:

```
$.cookie("example", "foo");
```

This cookie is set for the current path level and will be destroyed when the user closes their browser. If you want to make a cookie last longer, for example 10 days, do this:

```
$.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: 10 });
```

To make a cookie available for all paths on your domain, set the path to everything:

```
$.cookie("example", "foo", { path: '/' });
```

Or, if you want to isolate the cookie to a single path or directory, use this instead:

```
$.cookie("example", "foo", { path: '/admin' });
```

To get the value of the cookie, you could show it's value inside an alert box, like so:

```
alert( $.cookie("example") );
```

Or, put it inside a variable for later use:

```
var cookievalue = $.cookie('example');
```

Finally, to delete a cookie, simply set the value to `null`. Note that simply setting an empty string will not remove the cookie, just clear its value.

```
$.cookie("example", null);
```

Comment: not jQuery, but a jQuery plugin https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.cookie` and yes, yes you can.

Comment: I think it is document.cookie only

Answer (score 0):

Set a cookie

```
$.cookie("example", "foo"); // Sample 1
$.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: 7 }); // Sample 2
$.cookie("example", "foo", { path: '/admin', expires: 7 }); // Sample 3
```

Get a cookie

```
alert( $.cookie("example") );
```

Delete the cookie

```
$.cookie("example", null);
```

[Plugin jquery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)